# iOS branch.io Pass an user developer identity to an install event in webhook

Tags: ios, branch.io

We use a webhook for an install event. In our iOS app we set the identity with the method `Branch.getInstance().setIdentity()` before calling `Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions:...)`. But in the JSON response from a branch server about the INSTALL event we don't see `developer_identity` value. (But this value exist in an OPEN event)

Is it correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The INSTALL event occurs before the setIdentity() call in the lifecycle. Hence, this is the intended behavior and the INSTALL event will never have the developer identity.

Comment: How can I connect an INSTALL event in the back-end server with the user? Only using idfa?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You will need to use the IDFA/GAID from the Install event to tie it back.